# Problemas con Live Reload en carpetas compartidas en red

Tags: ionic, angular7, angular-cli

Estoy realizando una aplicación con Ionic y tengo problemas con la detección de cambios para la compilación automática.

El proyecto se encuentra en una carpeta compartida en red, es decir los archivos no están físicamente en la PC local de trabajo. Para acceder desde la consola al recurso compartido se usa el comando **net use** para mapear la unidad.

Al ejecutar **ionic serve** la aplicación compila y funciona correctamente en el navegador, el problema es que al realizar algún cambio en el código no lo detecta y no vuelve a compilar automáticamente.

Por otro lado, cuando la carpeta del proyecto está en la PC local de trabajo, los cambios se detectan y todo funciona correctamente pero necesito lograr que funcione accediendo a la carpeta compartida en la red.

He trabajado accediendo a una carpeta compartida en el servidor con proyectos en angular y no he tenido problemas con la detección de los cambios, pero con ionic no funciona.

¿Alguna sugerencia? ¿Alguien más tuvo el mismo inconveniente o tiene alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Estoy trabajando con **Ionic 5** y **Angular**.

**Angular CLI**: 8.1.3
**Node**: 13.0.0
**OS**: win32 x64
**Angular**: 8.1.3

Comment: Hola, Maria. Por que no usar git? Así siempre trabajas en local y con control de versiones.

Comment: Hola Angel, gracias por contestar. Actualmente es esta la estructura con la que se manejan en mi lugar de trabajo y por lo menos al corto plazo no es una posibilidad cambiar a git.